# Correct export in Premiere to Vimeo & YouTube in FULL RANGE 0-255

Tags: ffmpeg, premiere, color-correction, h.264

I'm working in Adobe Premiere on some sequences (Full HD, Progressive, 8bit).

In these sequences I added also some matte black backgrounds and after effects comps with black background and other plain colors.

If I export normally from premiere in h264 .mp4 the resulting file have it's colors shifted because Premiere tends to always apply a Limited Range (16-235) to the colors instead of Full Range (0-255).

What normally is a Pure Black RGB 0,0,0 becomes a Dark Gray 16,16,16 and the same happens to the other colors.

For the ones who are wondering why there are these ranges, the Limited Range (16-235) is used in HDTVs and I fear that Premiere enforce this settings always.. But in Youtube and Vimeo you can fully use the 0-255!

So..

What is the correct workflow to have Premiere export h264 video files in full range 0-255 ?

It isn't a problem is given by the REC 709 space right? Could be that premiere only exports h264/h265 files in Limited range ?

I tried export in DNX and convert in h264 with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "dnx.mov" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -b:v 12000k -profile:v main -level:v 4.1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf format=yuv420p -dst_range 1 -color_range 2 -c:a copy h264.mov
```

But even doing this, the result is just a file marked somewhat in full range, VLC uses 0-255 even if some gradients are clipped in my opinion and if exported on Vimeo the result is still with the black shifted from 0 to 16 with a nice gray instead of black :(

Do the maximum color depth inside the premiere export panel make something?

Comment: `yuv420p` is limited range. `yuvj420p` is full range.

Comment: @Gyan Interesting.. so if I use that on ffmpeg I should be able to achieve the full range with ffmpeg but for the original in premiere? I assume that premiere is unable to export nativeli in h264 full range.. there's another codec I could use compatible with full range ?

Comment: Probably some RGB codec, like QT Animation

Comment: @Gyan Oh i see, Premiere codecs doesn't have options like yuvj420p so you have to go for codecs that uses RGB